# kubectl not installed with gcloud SDK

Tags: kubernetes

I installed gcloud SDK and everything went fine. However I'm trying to use kubectl and it hasn't been installed.

I run the following commands:

```
gcloud components update preview
All components are up to date.
gcloud components update alpha
All components are up to date.
```

So seems like everything is up to date. However command kubectl is not there.

This is not a PATH issue because I checked the file in gcloud's bin folder and it is there as it is in other of my installations where it was installed correctly.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on AWS.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe the problem is that these are 32-bit instances on AWS.

Comment: What I ended up doing was to manually download the 32-bits version from Google Storage: https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v0.18.2/bin/linux/386/kubectl

Comment: Did you try gcloud components update kubectl? See https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/gke/util.sh#L103

Comment: That's correct Robert! Not sure why, but I set it up in another computer a few days ago and didn't have to do that. Also didn't see that in the docs. Maybe it is new. So that seems to be the issue. If you put that as an answer I will take it as valid. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that you need to run `gcloud components update kubectl`. I'm not sure why (this didn't used to be required).

Comment: More precisely you need to install the component, you're command work because update will install it if not already installed. The install command is: gcloud components install kubectl

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, everything was uptodate, but it didn't recognize "**kubectl**"

Nevertheless, found it here::

```
find / -name 'kubectl'
```

> /usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin/kubectl

So added the path to **/etc/bash.bashrc** (ubuntu 14.04)

```
echo "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin"  >> /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Relogged in to SDK node and to the google cloud, and now it works fine:

```
kubectl
```

> kubectl controls the Kubernetes cluster manager.
>
> Find more information at https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes.
>   ...

Answer (score -1):

Note that you can also install via homebrew using:

`brew uninstall kubernetes-cli`

but I wouldn't recommend that, since it was installing version 0.17.1 and gcloud is currently using 18.1.

I just uninstalled the homebrew version and used the accepted answer to grab it via gcloud: `gcloud components update kubectl`